# how to write xpath to click on the "add" button

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<tr>
<td id="Action1_Td_Add">
<a id="Action1_But_Add" class="btn cus-action-btn-add btn-xs" href="javascript:__doPostBack('Action1$But_Add','')" alternatetext="" title="Add" onclick="return Add_Click();">
<i class="fa fa-plus"/>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I have tried the using the css selector.
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Add']")).click();`
but the action was not preformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem with xpath. Use Java Script click instead of click. Like this, Hope this will help.

```html
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Add']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```